# Strange behaviour when input element switches type to hidden

Tags: javascript, html

I discovered a strange behavior of input text/hidden elements and I would like to know why this happens.

I have an input text box that has a value, let's say "test". I delete the input element value and I change the type of this element into "hidden". If now I switch it back to "text" the original value is there! If you don't fully delete the value of the text element but change it your changes are preserved. Why if you clear the element value this change is not preserved?

I created a fiddle that can show you what I mean.

```js
function toggler() {
  var iobj = document.getElementById('test');
  if (iobj.type == 'text') {
    iobj.type = 'hidden';
  } else {
    iobj.type = 'text';
  }
}
```

```html
<button name="toggle" type="button" onclick="toggler()">Toggle</button><br /><br />
<input type="text" name="test" id="test" value="sample" />
```

Comment: Not happening on "chrome". Value stays "changed" as expected. Welcome to the world of cross-browser-compatible javascript coding :-)

Comment: I assume changing the type triggers the `attributeChangedCallback()` on the `value` attribute because the value is ''.

Comment: Not able to replicate

Comment: Reproducable in the latest Firefox/Windows.

Comment: Edge working as expected as well.

Comment: There's language about this exact thing in the HTML spec. I think you're seeing what's supposed to happen.  Note that if you don't completely erase the value, and change "sample" to "x" for example, it remains the same when toggled back to "text".

Comment: If you change the value to anything non-empty, the value survives the toggle.

Comment: @connexo yes - that's as per the spec.

Comment: In Chrome it works correctly... In Firefox works as I described in my original post.

Comment: @connexo not on chrome and edge. Every change is reflected, no matter if you remove, change or clear the value. Toggle has no impact.

Comment: @Elxis Firefox is correct, Chrome is wrong. https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#states-of-the-type-attribute and scroll up some.

Comment: @Pointy It's a expendable discussion, which browser does it right: Majority wins, even if it's wrong according to specifications.

Comment: A checked your fiddle and did everything you told. It is working fine. i.e. When I change input value and toggle the changes are preserved.

Comment: @dognose well the HTML5 "living spec" is supposed to be the consensus among existing implementations. That part of the spec is extremely confusing because there are so many variables involved. Setting the `value` back to the original attribute value is something that is supposed to happen *sometimes* when the `type` changes, but it's tricky to know exactly what that means.

Comment: @Pointy from a logical point of view, I disagree: IF i modify the value of the text field, and click the "toggle" button: I'd expect that the valuechange / blur event is fired prior to the button click event. Hence, the modified values should be "submitted" to the dom. So, my Expactation is: Toggling the field back to a visible state shows the updated value. (which is happening in chrome and edge)

Comment: @dognose well I'm not saying which behavior is "better"; I'm just saying that the spec for what happens when the `type` property is changed is anything but obvious, and there is definitely language in the spec that says that *sometimes* the `value` property should be changed back to the property of the "value" attribute.

Comment: @Pointy: Your right. Basic question: "Do you apply the constraints, applying while it was `text` - or do you apply the constraints of `hidden` now."

Comment: Changing type of an input has never been a good idea anyway.

Comment: @undefined agreed, and the fact that this is a head-scratcher is due in no small part to the fact that I (and probably lots of other question-answerers) have had very limited experience with the effects of that in practice.

Comment: @Pointy The specs write "The input (hidden) element represents a value that is not intended to be examined or manipulated by the user." OK, but I clear the value when its type is "text", not "hidden"

Comment: @Elxis I agree that the behavior is weird and unexpected. It's a strange corner of DOM semantics and rules, in my opinion.

Comment: @Pointy Yes, changing `type` of an input happens so rarely. One can easily use CSS for hiding an input. – In this case, Firefox uses the last non-empty value of the input as it's value when the type is changed, Chrome doesn't.

Answer (score 6):

This has something to do with how different browsers handle `defaultValue` property of the inputs, whenever their `type` is changed. In this case, when the input `type` is changed and the `.value` is empty, Firefox uses the last non-empty value as `.defaultValue` property of the input. When the type is changed into `text`, Firefox uses the `.defaultValue` property for setting current `.value` property of the input. Chrome doesn't do this, i.e. it uses the last value, empty or non-empty, as the `.defaultValue`.

[Here is a demo on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8y64nuws/). Comparing the logged values on Firefox and Chrome console, should demonstrate the different behaviors.

I should also mention that according to my experience/knowledge, Firefox is more standards-compliant than other browsers.

That being said, changing type of an input has never been a good idea. Form elements are very different and browsers handle the case in different ways.

Comment: A note: if you want to hide an input element *without* changing it's type to "hidden", it's a good idea to use CSS to make it `position: absolute` and `left: -10000px`. If you make an input hidden via `display: none` or something like that, IE will consider it to be disabled when a surrounding form is submitted.

Comment: @Pointy Good point! I didn't know that. Does IE consider an input `disabled` also when it's parent is hidden?

Comment: Yes. IE and Edge treat anything that's explicitly hidden as not being part of the "active" form. Placing the elements completely out of view as in my comment is fine, but making them hidden via the CSS "display" property or, I think, via the "visibility" property will make those browsers treat the elements as being "not there". Those browsers are also picky about setting focus to hidden elements.

Comment: I will add that I'm not 100% sure that Edge behaves the same way as the IE lineage.

Comment: I decided how to deal with my problem. Instead of switching the type property I switch the element class (display/visibility) and works fine. Even on Edge works fine. On Firefox/Chrome/Edge "display:none / visibility:hidden" elements submit their values properly and everything works as expected. I don't know for Internet Explorer, I don't have it.

Comment: This is why I asked my initial question. I created a multilingual input text field (it is much prettier and advanced than the fiddle) http://jsfiddle.net/japfr93k/19/